# GYGABYTE 970A-DS3P NO USB

Tags: usb

Since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I do not have USB support and therefore unable to install the OS on my GYGABYTE 970A-DS3P motherboard (very common here in Brazil) and I thought that 18.04 would solve this, but I still have no keyboard / mouse or any other type of USB interface.

Comment: What does `sudo lshw` show you? What does `journalctl -b 0 _KERNEL_SUBSYSTEM=usb` show you?

Comment: Common IOMMU issue with this or similar models: [SOLVED] GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0 uses this boot parameter: amd_iommu=on iommu=pt  & UEFI settings
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370
 &  GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel - IOMMU GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but regarding the problems with IOMMU by software I already do this in 16.04, I mean the native support in the kernel, I thought they would implement this correction already in this LTS but unfortunately they have not corrected and I do not even know if there is any way of pressing AMD in relation to these Drivers, but that is another matter ... I thank you for your support.